# xUNIT softwaretest with .NET CORE and Docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, xunit

I have a solution which contains two projects which has the following structure:

[image]

The project "TestWebApp" is a xUnit testproject and contains the software tests. The project "WebApplication" the software which should be tested with the testproject.

The software works fine but by now i would like to build a docker container which should be included in a gitlab ci-cd pipeline. My question contains two steps:

1. Should i build a container which contains the business application ("WebApplication") and the software test ("TestWebApp")? If this is the case how could i do that? How can i run the software test in the container? My Dockerfile looks like the following

```sh
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj", "WebApplication1/"]
COPY ["TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj", "TestWebApp/"]

# ------------------SOFTWARE TEST-------------------------------------------------------------

RUN dotnet restore "TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj" -c Release
RUN dotnet test --no-build -c Release --results-directory /testresults --logger "trx;LogFileName=test_result.xml" TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj

# ------------------WEB APP-------------------------------------------------------------
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication1"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app


FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
COPY --from=test /testresults .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

If i try it like the following dockerfile i get this error:

```
------
 > FROM docker.io/library/test:latest:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

2. If I shouldn't build a container with business application and test - what would be the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to build them both in the docker container -- in fact, you'd *want* to do that; because you want your tests to run on every build of your CI/CD pipeline.  The trick is they'll be in your initial docker image; but not in the one that gets deployed; and your Dockerfile code shows you're already doing that with the `final`.

The steps in your docker image should look a bit like this:

- Build Project
- Build Tests
- Run Tests
- Copy Deployable objects to deployable docker image

That final artifact, the deployable artifacts (without your tests) is what gets deployed; but this ensures your tests get run on every build.

So inyour answer, the only thing that's missing (at least from my eyeballing it) is a `dotnet test` for your test project between the `build` and `final`.

Comment: hi george, thanks for your fast deploy. could you check my updated dockerfile. thanks for your help.

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler It seems fine; does it produce a build artifact when the tests pass; and more importantly, when the tests fail, does it return a non-zero exit code and cause the build to fail? You'll want to test those things.

Comment: Currently the dockerfile produces the error which i posted below. The RUN dotnet restore "TestWebApp/TestWebApp.csproj" is canceled.

Comment: I think that the dockerfile tries to pull this image docker.io/library/test:latest which is not available. Any help for this?

Comment: Am i missing a docker pull or something like this in my dockerfile?